# Make ascii string from utf8 input

Tags: macros

I want to define a command that will take a name and create a readable string from it, that can be used as a filename. Something like

`John Doe` -> `doe-john`.

However, I want to avoid special characters, i.e. replace non-ascii characters by their ascii equivalent. That is, I need a macro that will remove accents and replace some special letters, e.g.

`æüßéñ` -> `aeuessen`.

Is there a way to do this in LaTeX with reasonable effort?

Comment: the amount of effort really is proportional to how much input you want to support. it's easy enough to define a function that allows you to specify what to do with each character, but then do you want to map a few dozen european accented characters, or also transliterate cyrillic and greek and a few thousand asian characters and ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't need to go beyond european alphabets, but I feel like that list is quite long as it is. I was hoping for some way to just strip any accents off a given character (without needing to resort to a list of every possibility). If I need to consider replacements like umlauts separately (with a list), that's fine, i guess.

Comment: unicode isn't organised in a way that makes stripping accents possible other than a lookup table (although of course in some languages that table may be in some standard string library, but tex you need to do it by hand) I see egreg's posted something (not how I'd have done it but either way you need to make a long list of replacements)

Comment: If you're using `inputenc` (rather than XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX) then you could let `\IeC` and all the accent commands to `\@firstofone`. (The `glossaries` package's `\glsnoidxstripaccents` does this to strip accents from the sort values when using TeX to sort.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot that's not a bad idea, you should post an answer, it may prevent egreg getting a tick, which is always a good thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just tried `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{glossaries} \begin{document} {\glsnoidxstripaccents æüßéñ} \end{document}` but for some reason it's not stripping the acute accent. Never noticed that before. I'll have to work out why before posting an answer.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot  `\@tabacckludge` I'd guess :-) (see `utf8enc.dfu`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the pointer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `inputenc` (rather than XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX) you can take advantage of the fact that `inputenc` turns the extended characters into accent commands. For example, `ü` expands to `\IeC{\"u}`. So you can temporarily redefine the accent commands to strip them out.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stripaccents}[2]{%
 \begingroup
  % strip accents:
  \let\add@accent\@secondoftwo
  % provide replacement strings:
  \def\AE{AE}%
  \def\ae{ae}%
  \def\OE{OE}%
  \def\oe{oe}%
  \def\AA{AA}%
  \def\aa{aa}%
  \def\L{L}%
  \def\l{l}%
  \def\O{O}%
  \def\o{o}%
  \def\SS{SS}%
  \def\ss{ss}%
  \def\th{th}%
  \def\TH{TH}%
  \def\dh{dh}%
  \def\DH{DH}%
  \xdef#1{#2}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\stripaccents\tmp{æüßéñ}
\show\tmp
\end{document}
```

This shows:

```
> \tmp=macro:
->aeussen.
```

If you have any other commands that are likely to occur in your input, you'll need to add them to `\stripaccents` so that they expand into something sensible.

For the umlauts, you could temporarily redefine `\"` so that it appends `e` to its argument:

```
\newcommand{\stripaccents}[2]{%
 \begingroup
  \def\"##1{##1e}% umlaut
  \let\add@accent\@secondoftwo
  \def\AE{AE}%
  \def\ae{ae}%
  \def\OE{OE}%
  \def\oe{oe}%
  \def\AA{AA}%
  \def\aa{aa}%
  \def\L{L}%
  \def\l{l}%
  \def\O{O}%
  \def\o{o}%
  \def\SS{SS}%
  \def\ss{ss}%
  \def\th{th}%
  \def\TH{TH}%
  \def\dh{dh}%
  \def\DH{DH}%
  \xdef#1{#2}%
 \endgroup
}
```

This now shows:

```
> \tmp=macro:
->aeuessen.
```

With T1 encoding you also need:

```
\let\@text@composite@x\@secondoftwo
```

in the definition of `\stripaccents`, as mentioned in your comment.

Comment: This is what I was hoping for! I am also using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` which breaks this solution. However, adding `\let\@text@composite@x\@secondoftwo` to the definition of `\stripaccents` rectifies this. May be worth adding to the answer.

Comment: @schtandard Sorry, I should have checked with `T1`. I'll add it in.

Comment: One more thing I noticed: `fontenc` expands `å` to `\r a`, not `\aa`. Thus, instead of `\AA` and `\aa` we have to redefine `\r`.

Comment: @schtandard Perhaps the best definition would be `\def\r##1{##1##1}` assuming that the ring accent indicates a long vowel. (If not, then a more complex definition would be required that expands the argument to something appropriate. For example, if `\r a` needs to be `aa` but `\r y` needs to be `uo`.)

Comment: agreed. `\def\r##1{##1##1}` should be sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 4):

You have to populate the list yourself, according to the given examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq

\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq { {æ}{ae} }
\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq { {ä}{ae} }
\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq { {ö}{oe} }
\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq { {ü}{ue} }
\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq { {ß}{ss} }
\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq { {ñ}{n} }
\seq_gput_right:Nn \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq { {é}{e} }

\tl_new:N \l_schtandard_input_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\makestring}{om}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_schtandard_input_tl { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_schtandard_search_replace_seq
   {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN ##1 \l_schtandard_input_tl
   }
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_schtandard_input_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_schtandard_input_tl
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makestring{æüßéñ}

\makestring[\foo]{æüßéñ}\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And there I thought the days of me not knowing most of the commands in an answer where over... Guess it's time to learn expl3.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need filenames, but do not need them to be "human readable", then you could take advantage of `\pdfstringdef`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`| 0 \catcode`\\ 12
|gdef|makestring@i\#1#2#3#4%
     {#1#2#3|if|relax#4|expandafter|@gobbletwo|fi|makestring@i#4}
|endgroup
\newcommand*{\makestring}[2]{%
   \pdfstringdef\makestring@{#2}%
   \edef#1{\expandafter\makestring@i\makestring@\relax}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\makestring{\foo}{æüßéñ}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A variation on this theme which is much more efficient, it show the utf8 bytes. One could produce in hexadecimal if desired. (in fact there are possibly macros in `utf8.def` which could be used here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\MakeString[2]{%
   \begingroup
    \def\UTFviii@two@octets##1##2{\the\numexpr`##1\relax\the\numexpr`##2}%
    \def\UTFviii@three@octets##1##2##3{\the\numexpr`##1\relax\the\numexpr`##2\relax\the\numexpr`##3\relax}%
    \def\UTFviii@four@octets##1##2##3##4{\the\numexpr`##1\relax\the\numexpr`##2\relax\the\numexpr`##3\relax\the\numexpr`##4\relax}%
   \xdef#1{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\MakeString{\foo}{æüßéñ}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\show\foo
\end{document}
```

Produces:

```
> \foo=macro:
->195166195188195159195169195177.
l.23 \show\foo
```

I should improve so that each byte produce a three-digits decimal, here leading zeros are stripped!

---

Ok here it is with no stripping and 2-hex digits per byte.

**edit** removed usage of extra package. Defined `\Byte@tohex` macro possibly already provided by `utf8-inputenc` internally, not checked.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
% I have not checked but maybe utf8-inputenc provides already
% similar macro (not even using e-TeX)
\def\Byte@tohex #1%
   {\expandafter
    \Byte@tohex@\the\numexpr(`#1+8)/16-1\expandafter
    .\the\numexpr`#1.}%
\def\Byte@tohex@ #1.#2.%
   {\Byte@onehex #1.%
    \expandafter\Byte@onehex\the\numexpr #2-16*#1.%
   }
\def\Byte@onehex #1.%
   {\ifcase #1
    0\or1\or2\or3\or4\or5\or6\or7\or8\or9%
     \or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F%
   \fi
   }%
\newcommand*\MakeString[2]{%
   \begingroup
    \def\UTFviii@two@octets##1##2{\Byte@tohex{##1}\Byte@tohex{##2}}%
    \def\UTFviii@three@octets##1##2##3{\Byte@tohex{##1}\Byte@tohex{##2}\Byte@tohex{##3}}%
    \def\UTFviii@four@octets##1##2##3##4{\Byte@tohex{##1}\Byte@tohex{##2}\Byte@tohex{##3}\Byte@tohex{##4}}%
   \xdef#1{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\MakeString{\foo}{æüßéñ}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\show\foo
\end{document}
```

produces in log

```
> \foo=macro:
->C3A6C3BCC39FC3A9C3B1.
l.27 \show\foo
```

Comment: I see now OP said `create a readable string` but I am not sure if that meant `create a recognizable string` this is why I am posting this nevertheless.

Comment: of course this is also a `recognizable string` for the happy ones versed in octal sequences and `UTF-16BE`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am only the lazy guy... I should rather imitate utf8-inputenc but use it to produce an octal or hex sequence straight from the utf8-encoded source. The `\pdfstringdef` is rather big macro and makes many things like so needed here. But it is time for Lunch!

Comment: (I postponed lunch...)

Comment: Big brother is watching!

Comment: "Choose a Lazy Person To Do a Hard Job Because That Person Will Find an Easy Way To Do It" (https://quoteinvestigator.com/2014/02/26/lazy-job/)

Comment: Why not just `\pdfescapehex` the detokenized version of the string? `\message{\pdfescapehex\expandafter{\detokenize{éçß☺}}}`

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I knew it was you when I saw ``Why not just pdfescapehex`` ;-) Somehow I am still very unfamiliar with `\pdfescapehex` and `\pdfescapestring` because I never used them during `xint` development, for desire of staying multi-engine. But sure, +1 !

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch is  your suggestion an illustration of [Steven's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393225/make-ascii-string-from-utf8-input/393281?noredirect=1#comment977271_393281) ?

Comment: @jfbu It is.  Alternatively you could do `\def\MakeStringIter#1{-\number\expandafter\`#1\MakeStringIter}\long\def\MakeString#1{\expandafter\MakeStringIter\detokenize{#1}\string}` (ok the cleanup could be better)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I guess you meant ``\expandafter`\expandafter#1\MakeStringIter`` ?

Comment: @jfbu; no :) The `\expandafter` only does something meaningful at the last iteration, where it expands `\string`, thus leaving `\number\`\MakeStringIter` (where `\MakeStringIter` is detokenized).  The result always ends with the horrible string `-92MakeStringIter`...

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I was pondering about your "ok the cleanup could be better" and indeed suspecting the worst (!)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch use `{^^@\@gobble}` instead of `\string` ? (and no `\expandafter` at all because lack of space will trigger continued expansion) (maybe we need a space for the last one)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch so used to `\romannumeral`... no way to let `\number` expand to nothing? And the `^^@` needs to assign for example `catcode0 12 ` beforehand. And indeed a space token at very end.

Comment: @jfbu: (1) The `\expandafter` really didn't do anything until the last step, it didn't trigger further expansion; (2) `\number` always expands to something (at best 0); (3) I wasn't serious.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch (1) I had seen that and this why I asked in jest about ``\expandafter`\expandafter#1\MakeStringIter`` but termination would have been compromized... and (1a) I had not seen the `\string` at that time and (1b) at that time I did not recall that ``\number`\string...`` would not have been legit. About (2), yes I lamented that on some occasion because same for `\the\numexpr` which is what I use most. (3) The problem of the cleanup gave me a hint that you may not have been fully conscious a.t.t.o.w.