# Remove special characters

Tags: characters

Is there a simple way to remove special characters (such as `é`, `É`, `à`, `ç` etc.) from a given string, via a command `\removeSpecialCharacters{...}`?

## More precisely

I would like to remove all characters but `a...zA...Z0...9` and, if possible, replace the accented characters by the non-accented characters.

Comment: Please, provide more context. What is the meaning of "special" here? What makes some accented letters special? What is the purpose? How are the input strings defined (with TeX markup commands, ...)? Is an expandable solution needed? ...

Comment: Does "special" mean, "any letter character which doesn't have an ASCII code value between 65 and 90 for uppercase letters and 97 and 122 for lowercase letters"? What about "special" *non-letter* characters, i.e., non-letter characters which don't have an ASCII code value below 127? Should they be removed as well?

Comment: Do you mean stripping accents as in [Make ascii string from utf8 input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393225/make-ascii-string-from-utf8-input)

Comment: Question is now clear ... but to me is a dupe of the older one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit hard to know exactly what you mean by remove, and what you mean by special.

You can either remove the character containing the accent or cedilla (see below), 
 or you can remove the accents, and the cedilla, from these characters.

For removing accents you can just temporary redefine the `\add@accent`, as inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393297/85834):

The following code will remove **characters** containing accents and the c-cedilla (`ç`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\removeSpecialCharacters[1]{
  \begingroup
  \let\c\@gobble% Removes the c-cedilla (ç)
  \renewcommand\add@accent[2]{}
  #1
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \removeSpecialCharacters{Héllo world} %<-- Hllo world
\end{document}
```

Whilst this will remove **accents** from the characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\removeSpecialCharacters[1]{
  \begingroup
  \let\c\relax% Removes the cedilla (ç -> c)
  \renewcommand\add@accent[2]{##2}
  #1
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \removeSpecialCharacters{éÉàç} %<- returns eEac
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you forget the `makeatother`?

Comment: @Colas Yes. Fixed :)